# How to save changed prop data on form submit in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using Vuejs with Inertiajs and Laravel.

The data is coming from a database and is then passed to my Vue component as a prop via Inertiajs

In the component the array is displayed (instead of items array, it will be looping through the `actualitems` array - which has the same structure as items array).

The user can change the quantity of the item and the new price is updated.

On form submit, how can I get all the data with the new changes?

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/sionafernandes/pen/oNLKLGX) Example

**HTML** -

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="app">
  <form @submit.prevent="submitForm">
    <ul id="list-example">
      <li v-for="item in items">
        <input type="text" v-model="item.name" readonly />
        <input type="number" v-model="item.price" readonly />
        <input type="number" v-model="item.quantity" min="1" />
        <input type="number" :value="item.quantity*item.price" readonly />
      </li>
    </ul>
    <input type="submit" value="Place order">
  </form>
</div>
```

**Vue** -

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#list-example",
  props: {
    actualitems: Array
  },
  data: {
    items: [
      { name: "Book", quantity: 5, price: 100, total: 500 },
      { name: "Pen", quantity: 2, price: 200, total: 400 },
      { name: "Marker", quantity: 7, price: 100, total: 700 }
    ]
  }
});
```

Comment: The app root can't have `props` because those come from a parent element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Codepen you're using Vue 1.x which is deprecated, use Vue 2.x or Vue 3.x.

You're also mounting your app *inside* the form. I'd suggest mounting it outside the form, then you can do `@submit.prevent="submitForm"` and define a method which handles submitting the form data.

Here's an example:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    items: [{
        name: "Book",
        quantity: 5,
        price: 100,
        total: 500
      },
      {
        name: "Pen",
        quantity: 2,
        price: 200,
        total: 400
      },
      {
        name: "Marker",
        quantity: 7,
        price: 100,
        total: 700
      }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    submitForm() {
      console.log(this.items)
    },
    calculateTotal(index) {
      const item = this.items[index];
      
      item.total = item.quantity * item.price;
    }
  }
});

Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.config.devtools = false;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid" id="app">
  <form @submit.prevent="submitForm">
    <ul id="list-example">
      <li v-for="(item, index) in items">
        <input type="text" :value="item.name" readonly />
        <input type="number" v-model="item.price" readonly />
        <input @input="calculateTotal(index)" type="number" v-model="item.quantity" min="1" />
        <input type="number" :value="item.total" readonly />
      </li>
    </ul>
    <input type="submit" value="Place order">
  </form>
</div>
```

Also, as @Dan said, your app root can't accept props as there's no component above it to pass them.

Comment: Hi Daniel . Once it is submitted, the total price still is the initial price because v-bind is used. How can this be changed?

Comment: No problem. You can use the `@input` event to change the price whenever the number input is changed. I've edited my snippet to include this.